# Why the URL is refused but it is in the frame-ancestors

Tags: iframe

The URL https://keycloak.uedasoft.com/ is refused to be the ancestor of the iframe by chrome, but contradictory the error is also reported as it is specified in the **frame-ancestors** as follows:

```
Refused to frame 'https://keycloak.uedasoft.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' https://keycloak.uedasoft.com/".
```

What is the possible cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems just chrome's **inappropriate** error message. Firebox reported it as follows:

```
404 Not Found
```

Actuary, I've confirmed firefox's message is correct for the root cause.